# Flutter AWS Amplify override deafult theme for SignUpFormField.birthdate

Tags: flutter, aws-amplify

I am using the Authenticator widget from AWS Amplify and trying to override the default theme for the birthdate form field to simply make some modifications to the UI for the DatePicker Widget.

```
SignUpForm.custom(fields: [
    SignUpFormField.email(required: true),
    SignUpFormField.birthdate(required: true)
```

I know I can simply wrap the whole SignUpForm field with a theme, and modify the Theme as such, but I ONLY want to override the Theme for the birthdate SignUpFormField and not the email Form Field. This is because I want to change the following themeData parameter:

```
textTheme: TextTheme(bodyLarge: TextStyle(color: Colors.black))
```

Wrapping the whole SignUpForm.custom with Theme will end up changing the text for both widgets, email and birthdate, while what I want is to ONLY change it for birthdate..

First time asking a question so please bear with me and let me know if any addition information is needed!

Appreicate the help in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

My Solution to this was simply forking the amplify_authenticator package, and making modifications to that package manually. Then after making the changes, I modified the pubspec.yaml in my flutter app repo to direct amplify_authenticator to point to the forked github repo.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).